# Bash shell script: recursively cat TXT files in folders

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line

I have a directory of files with a structure like below:

```
./DIR01/2019-01-01/Log.txt
./DIR01/2019-01-01/Log.txt.1
./DIR01/2019-01-02/Log.txt
./DIR01/2019-01-03/Log.txt
./DIR01/2019-01-03/Log.txt.1
...
./DIR02/2019-01-01/Log.txt
./DIR02/2019-01-01/Log.txt.1
...
./DIR03/2019-01-01/Log.txt
```

...and so on.
Each `DIRxx` directory has a number of subdirectories named by date, which themselves have a number of log files that need to be concatenated. The number of text files to concatenate varies, but could theoretically could be as many as 5. I would like to see the following command performed for each set of files within the dated directories (note that the files must be concatenated in reverse order):

```
cd ./DIR01/2019-01-01/
cat Log.txt.4 Log.txt.3 Log.txt.2 Log.txt.1 Log.txt > ../../Log.txt_2019-01-01_DIR01.txt
```

(I understand the above command will give an error that certain files do not exist, but the `cat` will do what I need of it anyways)
Aside from `cd`ing into each directory and running the above `cat` command, how can I script this into a Bash shell script?

Comment: use `find` with `-exec`

Comment: What *specific* part of this are you having trouble with? Is it taking your directory name and converting the `/`s to `_`s? Is it looping over directories? We probably have existing Q&A entries in the knowledgebase about all these things, if you narrow your question enough to be about the specific operations you're having trouble determining how to perform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to concatenate all files in all subdirectories whose name starts with `Log.txt`, you could do something like this:

```
for dir in DIR*/*; do 
    date=${dir##*/}; 
    dirname=${dir%%/*}; 
    cat $dir/Log.txt* > Log.txt_"${date}"_"${dirname}".txt; 
done
```

If you need the files in reverse numerical order, from 5 to 1 and then `Log.txt`, you can do this:

```
for dir in DIR*/*; do 
    date=${dir##*/}; 
    dirname=${dir%%/*}; 
    cat $dir/Log.txt.{5..1} $dir/Log.txt > Log.txt_"${date}"_"${dirname}".txt; 
done
```

That will, as you mention in your question, complain for files that don't exist, but that's just a warning. If you don't want to see that, you can redirect error output (although that might cause you to miss legitimate error messages as well):

```
for dir in DIR*/*; do 
    date=${dir##*/}; 
    dirname=${dir%%/*}; 
    cat $dir/Log.txt.{5..1} $dir/Log.txt > Log.txt_"${date}"_"${dirname}".txt; 
done 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks! This is really close to getting me what I need, but the files are concatenated in reverse order. The files are timestamped, so they need to concatenated with Log.txt.2 first, then Log.txt.1 appended to it, then Log.txt appended to that. The above command appends the files in the reverse order.

Comment: @Eliot OK, see updated answer. But please edit your question to add this requirement.

Comment: Perfect, that works! I thought the description with my `cat` command would imply the requirement to concatenate them in reverse order, but I will clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Not as comprehensive as the other, but quick and easy. Use `find` and `sort` your output however you like (`-zrn` is `--zero-terminated` `--reverse` `--numeric-sort`) then iterate over it with `read`.

```
find . -type f -print0 |
sort -zrn |

while read -rd ''; do
    cat "$REPLY";
done >> log.txt
```